# How to display a user friendly message when token is invalid in springMVC web system?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, token

I am using springMVC to develop my web project and I faced the form resubmit problem.In order to solve this problem,I searched from the Internet and use interceptor to do it.The detail information is listed as below:

- The **Token** class:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Token {

    boolean save() default false;

    boolean remove() default false;
}
```

* The **Interceptor** class:

```
public class TokenInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
            Token annotation = method.getAnnotation(Token.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                boolean needSaveSession = annotation.save();
                if (needSaveSession) {
                    request.getSession(false).setAttribute("token", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                }
                boolean needRemoveSession = annotation.remove();
                if (needRemoveSession) {
                    if (isRepeatSubmit(request)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    request.getSession(false).removeAttribute("token");
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
        }
    }

    private boolean isRepeatSubmit(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String serverToken = (String) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("token");
        if (serverToken == null) {
            return true;
        }
        String clinetToken = request.getParameter("token");
        if (clinetToken == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!serverToken.equals(clinetToken)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

- The **XML config** code block:

```
<!-- 拦截器配置 -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <!-- 配置Shiro拦截器，实现注册用户的注入 -->
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.storezhang.video.shiro.ShiroInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <!-- 配置Token拦截器，防止用户重复提交数据 -->
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.storezhang.web.spring.TokenInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

When I want to use token to prevent duplicate form submit,I need to add `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="${token}" />` to the relevant jsp page and add `@Token`
to the relevant controller method.

**Now my question is: using the code blocks above I can prevent duplicate form submit.But if the token is invalid the `preHandle` method will return false and thus a empty page will display to the user.What to should I do to change the code blocks above in order to give a user friendly message when the token is invalid?**